# How to send feature codes with a modem using AT commands

Tags: mac, modem

I have a ZTE usb modem that I need to use to send a feature code `*140*707#` to my network provider. How can I do this with console apps like `screen` and AT commands?

I've found [a page](http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/) that explains how to send SMS using AT commands but I need to send this feature code.

Comment: Looks like a phone number you need to dial, so you'd use `ATDT*140*707#` to dial it.

Comment: @ultrasawblade Hmm, this is strange. It responded "no carrier".

Comment: Might have to do another command to take the phone "off hook" first  Can't think of what it is off the top of my head.  Google "Hayes AT commands" for a list.